# Ascii characters in plus when running program

Tags: c

So this is my third attempt still not working properly, I want opinion about how do i need to solve this problem, let some advice please.This is how the text of the problem sound, it demand to use a function which convert number from base 10 to another base, this is the essential, and I can use only strings to save the conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool Convert(unsigned int number, unsigned int toBase, char * result, 
unsigned int resultMaxSize)
{char p;
int var;

if(number==0)
return false;
while(number>0)
{var=number%toBase;
if(var>=10)
{p=(char)var;
*result=p;
}
else
*result=var+'0';
number=number/toBase;
result++;
}
if(strlen(result)>resultMaxSize)
return false;
strrev(result);
printf("%s", result);
return true;
}

int main()
{char rezultat[200]={0};
unsigned int nr, n, baza;
char *ptr;
ptr=rezultat;
printf("Introduceti numarul de convertit ");
scanf("%d", &nr);
printf("\nIntroduceti baza in care convertim ");
scanf("%d", &baza);
printf("\nIntroduceti numarul de caractere maxim pe care il va avea 
rezultatul ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\n%d",Convert(nr, baza, rezultat, n));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char w[100];` ==> `char w[100] = {0};`

Comment: @pmg it is useless to set all characters to 0, `w[0] = 0;` is enough and faster ^^

Comment: @Sergiu I put an answer with some remarks, to use _itoa_ this is cheating ^^

Answer (score 0):

> when i print the string i have some ascii chracters in plus

As *pmg* said in a remark a way is to initialize *w* with 0s, else *strcat* applied on a non initialized array has an undefined behavior. A faster way is to just do `w[0] = 0;` because it is useless to set the other characters.

Some additional remarks

- you use *itoa*, note this function is not defined in ANSI-C and *gcc* doesn't not provide it, however is you use it just do `void Convert(unsigned int number, unsigned int toBase, char * result) { itoa(number, result, toBase); }`
- you produce the number in the reverse order adding the characters at the end,  this is why 14 produces 0111 rather than 1110.
- doing `itoa(number%toBase, s, 10);` rather than `itoa(number%toBase, s, toBase);` your program only works with a base <= 10.
- doing *strcat* always from the beginning of the array is more and more expensive each loop because it has to bypass already added characters.

I encourage you to rewrite your program to produce the right result including for bases greater than 10, and that time without using *itoa*

Comment: Thanks for advices, the program i just posted was what i made in some minutes i refined it and it works just for bases less than ten, you were right, i used strrev function to reverse the string,

Comment: By the way how do i close a topic on this site i am new and i don't want to let it on without a reason.